# Are bucket shims for mainstream Japanese cars interchangable?

Tags: parts, part-interchange

I have two Japanese cars ( a Mazda and a Nissan ) which use cams placed directly over the valves ( no rocker arm ) which contact a shim sitting on top of a bucket over the valve.  Are the shims used by different manufacturers all the same circumference such that I could use for example Toyota shims in a Nissan or Mazda or visa versa, or are the all different circumferences?  I.e. are these type of shims standardized?

Comment: Kindly ask a nearby shop if they have your size (diameter) shims and will swap a few with you (of same diameter, but differing thickness). I have had shops do this for no charge. Maybe kick the guy a couple dollars for his time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost never will you find two sets of shims from different manufacturers that are identical.  That said, it's a shim.  You can reshape a larger one if need be, though it's a hack job.

So unless you really want to go DIY, no, they're not interchangeable even if they're the right thickness.

Comment: How do you know ?

Comment: It's been my experience doing valves on cars and motorcycles.